# unresolved external symbol, tbsi_context_create, tbsip_context_close

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When I compiled my project in Release configuration, it worked fine. However when I compiled it in another configuration it failed with link errors, such as:

> unresolved external symbol, **tbsi_context_create**,PROJECTNAME(FILENAME.obj)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a link error, I compared the '**additional include directories**' and "**additional library dependencies**', but both are exactly the same. After I tried many other things including a clean rebuild, then I realized that in the configuration that has issues, there is an additional preProcessor in Project Properties->Configuration Properties->c/c++->preProcessors.  Removing the preprocessor solves the issue.  It is not the first time I came across this link error, but I believe this is the first time that it is caused by an additional preprocessor.